# Request laravel retornando nulo

Tags: php, laravel, controller, request

Boa tarde pessoal, sou novo em frameworks
mas to com o seguinte probleminha:

o request ta voltando vazio pra minha consulta

desde já obrigado

```
"select * from `usuarios` where `cep` = ?"
```

meu controller ta assim

```
    public function procurapatrocinadorexecutar(Request $request){

   //dd($request);
   $dados = usuarios::where('cep', $request->cep)->toSql();
    dd($dados);
```

e a minha view assim ( já tem o csrf_field)

```
@extends('template.login')

@section('login')

<form class="form-signin" action="/PesquisarPatrocinador" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="panel periodic-login">
<div class="panel-body text-center">
  <h1 class="atomic-symbol">MMN</h1>
  <p class="atomic-mass">14.072110</p>
  <p class="element-name">Miminium</p>
  @include('includes.erros')
  <i class="icons icon-arrow-down"></i>
  <div class="form-group form-animate-text" style="margin-top:40px !important;">
    <input type="text" class="form-text" name="cep" required value="1305135">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Informe seu cep para pesquisa</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn col-md-12" value="Pesquisar"/>
</div>
@if(isset($dados))
@forelse ($dados as $dados)
<li>{{ $dados->usuario }}</li>
@empty
   aaa
@endforelse
@endif

<div class="text-center" style="padding:5px;">
  <a href="/">Voltar</a>
</div>
<div class="text-center" style="padding:5px;">
  <a href="/RecuperarSenha">Esqueceu a Senha? </a>
  <a href="/registrar_com/procurar">|Seja um Afilido, Procure um Patrocinador</a>
</div>
</div>
</form>
 @endsection
```

Comment: Seu select nao indica uma variavel ? Não entendi, e sua function não fecha as chaves?

Comment: é q eu coloquei só o trecho da função,

assim, o input cep não ta vindo no meu request

Comment: Seu action esta correto? Nao tem a extensão do arquivo somente o nome, exemplo action="salvar.php"

Comment: Route::post('/PesquisarPatrocinador','ControllerLogin@procurapatrocinadorexecutar'); esta é a minha rota

Comment: Porque toSql?..

Comment: só pra ver o retorno do sql

Comment: Ok @MatheusGonzales então da um `var_dump($request->cep);` e verifique o que retorna e depois se vir corretamente o `cep` faça um `var_dump(usuarios::where('cep', $request->cep)->get());`  e verifique o que retorna ... não tem por onde escapar! e também verifique se voltou o valor ... aquele `toSql()` só mostra realmente a SQL o `?` está no metodo `bindings` o problema então é na chegada da informação ou não não chegada na informação...